# Meaning of もの in this title/name

Tags: grammar, translation, usage, relative-clauses

An enemy (a monster) in a game I was reading about is called [時を食らうもの]{ときをくらうもの}, which is translated as "*Time Devourer*". Is the もの used as sort of a -er suffix, or does it have a different function?

Comment: Could it mean the thing that eats time? Mono meaning thing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> [時]{とき}を[食]{く}らうもの, which is translated as "Time Devourer"

As @bjorn says in the comment, the もの can be [者]{もの} "person/someone", as well as [物]{もの} "thing/object/something".

It's (perhaps intentionally) written in Hiragana because it's referring to a monster.

> Is the もの used as sort of a -er suffix, or does it have a different function?

The もの is a noun here, not a suffix. 時を食らうもの is a noun phrase, the relative clause 時を食らう modifying the noun もの.

「［[時]{とき}を[食]{く}らう］もの」-- *lit.* "someone/something [that eats time]" → "a time eater, a time devourer"

<sub>As pointed out by @bjorn, [者]{しゃ} is read as しゃ when used as a suffix. eg 「[担当者]{たんとうしゃ}」 person in charge 「[被害者]{ひがいしゃ}」 victim 「[技術者]{ぎじゅつしゃ}」 engineer ([者]{もの} can be used in compound words, too. eg 「[働]{はたら}き[者]{もの}」 hard worker 「[独]{ひと}り[者]{もの}」 unmarried person)

[物]{ぶつ} can also be used as a suffix. eg 「[爆発物]{ばくはつぶつ}」 explosives 「[出版物]{しゅっぱんぶつ}」 publications ([物]{もの} in compound nouns: 「[夏物]{なつもの}」 summer clothing 「[縁起物]{えんぎもの}」 good luck charm)</sub>

Comment: ググると、「時を**食**らう者」より、「時を**喰**らう者」って書かれてるページのほうが多いです。

Answer (score 2):

as JACK says, もの means "thing". And of course, 人{ひと} means "person".　However, "Thing that Eats Time/Time Eating Thing" or for example "Person That Eats Time/Time Eating Person" might feel not "punchy" enough as a title, so Japanese phrases using those kanji are sometimes translated into the "doer" form, such as "Time Devourer" (or "Time Eater").

Comment: Well, もの can also refer to a person, depending on the kanji. 物 for thing and 者 for person, a kanji that is usually used as a suffix and then pronounced しゃ, e.g. 医者｛いしゃ｝ = physician